# unknown host 'dl.google.com'. you may need to adjust the proxy settings in gradle un Android 4.2

Tags: android, android-studio, http, host

hi i just installed android studio 4.2 on my pc and i get the following error:
unknown host 'dl.google.com'. you may need to adjust the proxy settings in gradle
[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjMaS.jpg ][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjMaS.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjMaS.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzdAE.jpg)

Comment: Please provide code snippet, rather than screen-shot.

Answer (score 0):

Try HTTP proxy settings as on the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If internet is not connected so connect the internet and try.